# how to select multiple columns in QTable

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, qt-designer

I am working in c++/ubuntu. I've created a QTable :

```
  1 | 2
 -------
aaaa|bbbb
cccc|dddd
....|....
```

I would like to ask how can i select the entire row 2: cccc |dddd.

I did:

```
QModelIndexList indexes = ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selection().indexes();

    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.count(); ++i)

    {
        QModelIndex index = indexes.at(i);

        if (index.isValid())
        {

          QString s=index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
          QMessageBox noc;
                  noc.setText(s);
                  noc.exec();
        }


    }
```

But I see just tje cccc element seleted.

Appreciate. Thx very muxh!

Comment: QTable is deprecated Qt2|3 class. Which class you really use? Clarify your question, please. You want to select a row programmatically, or manually,by clicking it? Code you posted just displays selection, not trying to select something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a `Q3Table`, theres [an enum for handling selections](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/q3table.html#SelectionMode-enum) which is set using [this function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/q3table.html#selectionMode-prop).

If you're using `QTableView` (which is recommended) there is [a similar enum](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionBehavior-enum) and [function](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qabstractitemview.html#selectionBehavior-prop) to set it.

I hope this helps. As Raiv said in his comment, we can help you more if you clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [QTableView::selectedIndexes](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtableview.html#selectedIndexes). This function is for getting selected items.